# How is RonPaulCoin different from Bitcoin/Litecoin?

Tags: development, protocol, ronpaulcoin

Is RonPaulCoin a clone of Bitcoin/Litecoin or are there differences beyond the specifications such as coin limit and difficulty algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

RonPaulCoin uses Scrypt (like Litecoin). It is a **Litecoin clone** that only differs in the specifications:

- Limit: 2.1 Million
- Block time: 2 minutes
- Reward schedule: 1 RPC per block, halving every four years.
- Difficulty retargeting: Every 48 blocks (~96 minutes) with a maximum difficulty shift of 11%.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that coin has no technological innovations beyond a name change and a different block reward (max coins that could exist for it is apparently 2.1 million, instead of bitcoin's 21 million).

Comment: Ok, but I guess they all start like that until they contribute to the code.

Comment: No, not really. It's hard to change a coin's rules after it's launched.

Comment: Once launched, code becomes almost untouchable. If not done with the utmost care, even fixing a bug in an already-launched coin can break havoc. When Dogecoin devs. tried to fix a bug in the size of blocks, they had to deal with not one or 2, but THREE competing chains, all at the same time! Users had to get an emergency upgrade to fix the fix :(